# Parse Backbone Collection as Object, not Array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

I implementing nested comments using Backbone and Rails. My current implementation on the server side involves comment models that store the `parent_comment_id` (assuming they have one). When the app requests the comments for a given entity, I return a JSON object where the keys are the `parent_comment_id`s and the values are arrays of comments that have that a parent comment with that id. E.g.:

```
{
   "" : [{id: 1, content: "I'm an unnested comment, parent_comment_id: ""}],
   1  : [{id: 2, content: "I am nested under the comment with an id of 1", parent_comment_id: 1}, etc.],
   ...
}
```

The problem that I am currently having is that the Backbone collection corresponding to Comments returns an Array of length 1, where the sole element is the comments hash.

How can I override the parsing of the JSON response by the Comments collection so that the returned response is the JSON response hash and not an array?

Comment: Backbone collections want to store information internally in an array (stored internally as .models), so it's not clear what you really want here. Does each ID property map to a collection? Backbone models by default expect an object hash (stored internally as .attributes) and assigning an array as an attribute property isn't going to work the way you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further consideration, I decided that the best course of action was to offload the construction of the comments hash to the client side. By doing this, I can continue to parse collections as Arrays of objects as intended and then build the hash by calling the following method on the collection:

```
Jot.Collections.Comments = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  ...

  commentsByParent: function() {
    var commentsHash = {},
        key;

    this.models.forEach(function(c) {
      key = c.get('parent_comment_id');
      commentsHash[key] = commentsHash[key] || [];
      commentsHash[key].push(c);
    });

    return commentsHash;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override [collection.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method